# Not allow adding a tag to the box once it already exists

Tags: feature-request, support, tags

One tag can added more than once in the same question in [SE sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

[image]

I think this situation started when we using tags in boxes.

Is this normal?

Comment: As answered correctly, it's "by design", there is no validation at the moment (until you submit, of course). You can change this post to Feature Request asking to not allow adding a tag to the box once it already exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think yes this is normal. When you submit it you'll end up with one tag only.

I did dummy edit on your question (+ deleted stackexchange tag)

http://phpcode.eu/images/1315231530.php

but as you can see, there is only one "tags" tag shown in result

Comment: I can't ask it with same tag more than ones? If so, there is no problem.

Comment: @SonerGönül: see my edit on my answer

Comment: Still doesn't seem very intuitive. Seems messy. Maybe.